# How to run multiple testcase with One login testcase in selenium WD with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, gmail

Hi I have three class files. In first class, only one test case is used for login **Gmail** account. rest of the classes having only one test case and both are used for navigating **Inbox** and sent items. I have created `testng.xml` to run these multiple classes. Now the problem is when first class is being executed, I could be log in **Gmail** account. But when it comes to second class, I am unable to navigate to **Inbox** as I did not perform login operation in class 2 and class 3.

So it thrown me an error `Null Pointer Exception`. I know the reason why I am getting this exception. But I want to perform login action only one time but it should be available to all classes which means When I am going to execute class 2 and class 3, it should not throw error. It should continue from the class 1. How I can achieve this task.

I googled a lot. None of them helped me. Please suggest me any idea if you have. I have tried to extend my class also. I got no result. Please guide me where am I struggling?

**Following is my testng.xml**

```
<suite name="MynaTestCase">

    <test name="order">
        <classes>

            <class name="myPackage.Login" />
            <class name="myPackage.Inbox" />
            <class name="myPackage.SentItems" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

**Here is the Login Code**

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/vadmin/workspace/samplepjt/lib/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl+"/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Before suite executed");
    }

@Test
    public void LoginTest(){
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-user-secret")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_username")).clear();
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_username")).sendKeys(username);
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).clear();
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys(password);
         driver.findElement(By.id("signInButton")).click();
    }
```

**Here is the Inbox.Java**

```
@Test

    public void testcase1()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/ul/li[8]/a/div/p")).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/h4")).getText(), "Sections");

        driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='new_section']/div[3]/input")).submit();
    }
```

Comment: show us the class1 code...and class2 for better understanding..

Comment: "NullPointerException" is thrown when you try to access a variable that is declared null at runtime. However, we cannot really help you unless you show some code of your own. My guess is that you are trying to declare a new instance of a class every time you want to access a value? In this case you should use the static modifier.

Comment: Where and how do you define your WebDriver?

Comment: I have added the code. This is will be helpful for you

Comment: code may be not understandable. But i need to access the page from class without logging in again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you defined your WebDriver in the Login class, so the Inbox class won't see it.
To solve it, create an abstract class, which include the `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` classes and extend every test class with it.

**Abstract class**

```
public class MyAbstractClass
{
  public WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() {
    //...
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //...
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {
    //...
    this.driver.quit();
    //...
  }
}
```

**A Test Class**

```
public class MyTestClass extends MyAbstractClass
{
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    this.driver.get("http://google.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, so in your case extend `Login`, `Inbox` and `SentItems` classes with the Abstract Class.

Comment: i have another doubt. do i need to mention that abst class in tesng.xml also? how can i run my suite?? thru testng.xml ?? or normal way??

Comment: You don't have to change your `testng.xml`. Run your project like before :)

Comment: Could not login my page. but my web page is getting opened. what wrong i did?

Comment: Because your DataProvider is missing from the `Login` class.

Comment: no i have done evrything correctly. now i have change the code. that it you mentioned url in test class. but i have put it in abstract class itself. so now its working.

Comment: Nope...i still have another doubt. i extend the abstr class in login page.so i could login gmail. but when i try to access the inbox page, do i need to extend login class or abst class?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set `@Test(priority = 1)` for every test.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).